# Yii2 decimal format with decimalSeparator comma

Tags: yii2, formatting

I'm currently working with Yii2 framework and I need to set the default decimal separator symbol ',' instead of '.'. Searching on the internet I find this solution that doesn't work:

```
 'formatter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'thousandSeparator' => '.',
            'decimalSeparator' => ','
        ],
```

I put those lines in the web.php file in the 'components' section.
Do you have any further suggestion?

Comment: update your question  show the code where you need  the proper format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your settings look fine. You just have to make sure your output is handled by the Formatter. Like this... (try in your code)

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal(1234567.12);  // => 1.234.567,12
```

The Yii-framework format variables by using such methods "behind the scenes".

Comment: Hi! As you suggest I check if my output was handled by the formatter and it was not. Since I use some widget to display data in tables I have to specify the number format for these data. But now everything it's working fine. Thank you!